# Вписать TOR прокси в CURL

Tags: php, curl, tor, onion

Я использую https://github.com/Athlon1600/php-proxy-app
И мне хотелось бы запроксировать TOR через него

Я устанавливаю TOR на своем сервере и хочу пропустить запросы через сокс localhost:9050, чтобы php web proxy (ссылка на гит выше) работал для TOR сайтов

Код proxy.php в который я пытаюсь вписывать

$proxy = "localhost:9050"; $options[CURLOPT_PROXY] = $proxy;

Но это не помогает. Что я делаю не так и как правильно мне вписать proxy в CURL?

```
    <?php

namespace Proxy;

use Proxy\Event\ProxyEvent;
use Proxy\Http\Request;
use Proxy\Http\Response;
use Proxy\Config;

class Proxy {
    
    // Proxy script version
    const VERSION = '5.2.0';
    
    private $dispatcher;
    
    private $request;
    private $response;
    
    private $output_buffering = true;
    private $output_buffer = '';
    
    private $status_found = false;
    
    public function __construct(){
        // do nothing for now
    }
    
    public function setOutputBuffering($output_buffering){
        $this->output_buffering = $output_buffering;
    }
    
    private function header_callback($ch, $headers){
        $parts = explode(":", $headers, 2);
        
        // extract status code
        // if using proxy - we ignore this header: HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
        if(preg_match('/HTTP\/[\d.]+\s*(\d+)/', $headers, $matches) && stripos($headers, '200 Connection established') === false){
            
            $this->response->setStatusCode($matches[1]);
            $this->status_found = true;
        
        } else if(count($parts) == 2){
            
            $name = strtolower($parts[0]);
            $value = trim($parts[1]);
            
            // this must be a header: value line
            $this->response->headers->set($name, $value, false);
            
        } else if($this->status_found){
        
            // this is hacky but until anyone comes up with a better way...
            $event = new ProxyEvent(array('request' => $this->request, 'response' => $this->response, 'proxy' => &$this));
            
            // this is the end of headers - last line is always empty - notify the dispatcher about this
            $this->dispatch('request.sent', $event);
        }
        
        return strlen($headers);
    }
    
    private function write_callback($ch, $str){
    
        $len = strlen($str);
        
        $this->dispatch('curl.callback.write', new ProxyEvent(array(
            'request' => $this->request,
            'data' => $str
        )));
        
        // Do we buffer this piece of data for later output or not?
        if($this->output_buffering){
            $this->output_buffer .= $str;
        }
        
        return $len;
    }
    
    // TODO: move this all into its own Dispatcher class?
    // https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/5.3/src/Event/Emitter.php
    // https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php#L72
    private $listeners = array();
    
    // Proxy instance itself acts as a dispatcher!
    public function getEventDispatcher(){
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function addListener($event, $callback, $priority = 0){
        $this->listeners[$event][$priority][] = $callback;
    }
    
    public function addSubscriber($subscriber){
        if(method_exists($subscriber, 'subscribe')){
            $subscriber->subscribe($this);
        }
    }
    
    private function dispatch($event_name, $event){
        
        if(isset($this->listeners[$event_name])){
            $temp = (array)$this->listeners[$event_name];
            
            foreach($temp as $priority => $listeners){
                foreach( (array)$listeners as $listener){
                    if(is_callable($listener) ){
                        $listener($event);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public function forward(Request $request, $url){
    
        // change request URL
        $request->setUrl($url);
        
        // prepare request and response objects
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->response = new Response();
        
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 0,
            
            // don't return anything - we have other functions for that
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => false,
            CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
            
            // don't bother with ssl
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
            
            // we will take care of redirects
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => false,
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER     => false
        );
        
        // this is probably a good place to add custom curl options that way other critical options below would overwrite that
        $config_options = Config::get('curl', array());
        
        $options = array_merge_custom($options, $config_options);
        
        $options[CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION] = array($this, 'header_callback');
        $options[CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION] = array($this, 'write_callback');
        
        // Notify any listeners that the request is ready to be sent, and this is your last chance to make any modifications.
        $this->dispatch('request.before_send', new ProxyEvent(array(
            'request' => $this->request,
            'response' => $this->response
        )));
        
        // We may not even need to send this request if response is already available somewhere (CachePlugin)
        if($this->request->params->has('request.complete')){
            // do nothing?
        } else {
            //$proxy = "127.0.0.1:9050";
            // any plugin might have changed our URL by this point
            $options[CURLOPT_URL] = $this->request->getUri();
            
            // fill in the rest of cURL options
            $options[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = explode("\r\n", $this->request->getRawHeaders());
            $options[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] = $this->request->getMethod();
            $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] =  $this->request->getRawBody();
            //$options[CURLOPT_PROXY] = $proxy;
            
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
            
            // fetch the status - if exception if throw any at callbacks, then the error will be supressed
            $result = @curl_exec($ch);
            
            // there must have been an error if at this point
            if(!$result){
                $error = sprintf('(%d) %s', curl_errno($ch), curl_error($ch));
                throw new \Exception($error);
            }
            
            // we have output waiting in the buffer?
            $this->response->setContent($this->output_buffer);
            
            // saves memory I would assume?
            $this->output_buffer = null;
        }
        
        $this->dispatch('request.complete', new ProxyEvent(array(
            'request' => $this->request,
            'response' => $this->response
        )));
        
        return $this->response;
    }
}

?>
```

UPD
Сработало это:

```
CURLOPT_PROXY => '127.0.0.1:9050',
CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE => CURLPROXY_SOCKS5,
```

IP сменился, но к onion конекта нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте указать тип прокси `CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME`:

```php
$config['curl'] = array(
    CURLOPT_PROXY => '127.0.0.1:9050',
    CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE => CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME
);
```

или так:

```php
$config['curl'] = array(
    CURLOPT_PROXY => 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'
);
```

Comment: Срабатывает нормально, но именно в proxy.php он не срабатывает почему-то на .onion сайтах ... напишу в ответе ниже